# Can Lightning Pages created with Lightning App Builder be used for desktop?

Tags: lightning-apps, app

According to this site https://developer.salesforce.com/lightning Lightning App Builder can be used for both mobile devices and desktop, but I cannot find a way on how a Lightning Page can be opened in a Desktop Browser?

Except for the url `<salesforceInstance>.salesforce.com/one/one.app`, are there other ways I can open it in my browser?

Comment: Also, in one of the sessions with Salesforce, I have heard that Lightning App for Desktop is in Salesforce's product roadmap and will be launched soon. I expect to hear some official announcement during the Dreamforce this year.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid the text is incorrect. Lightning Pages can only be added to Salesforce1 (i.e. the mobile app) with [Summer 15](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_mobile_salesforce1_newfeat_appbuilder.htm).

Answer (score 2):

As this functionality is not supported OOB for Summer 15, you can work around Lightning's limitations by embedding your Lightning App in a Visualforce page.

```
<apex:page>
  <apex:iframe src="/one/one.app"></apex:iframe>
</apex:page>
```

Note: If your app is named "expenseTracker" and does not use a custom namespace, use "/c/expenseTracker.app" as the iframe's `src`.

Comment: The question was about Lightning Pages created in the Lightning App Builder, they are confusingly enough not the same as Lightning Apps (.app). Lightning Pages do not have a public, supported URL.

Comment: Refused to display 'https://mydomain.lightning.force.com/one/one.app' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'

guess this iframe trick doesnt work after recent update

Answer (score 0):

**Currently you can only use Lightning Components in the Salesforce1 Mobile App or a standalone app.**
Lightning Components have been built to be mobile first, but with responsive design in mind. So you can use them for both mobile and desktop (as a standalone app).