# Can Lightning App Builder apps be used from Visualforce?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, app-builder

Lightning Components can be presented in a Visualforce page as described in the [Use Lightning Components in Visualforce Pages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_visualforce.htm) documentation via an app that extends `ltng:outApp`. Given that this specific app configuration is required, am I correct in assuming that an app created via the [Lightning App Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lightning_app_builder_overview.htm) can't be presented in a Visualforce page?

(This [Can Lightning Pages created with Lightning App Builder be used for desktop?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/83773/can-lightning-pages-created-with-lightning-app-builder-be-used-for-desktop) is a slightly different question and quite old now.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lightning App Builder creates [Lightning Pages](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lightning_page_overview.htm&language=en_US&type=0) ([FlexiPage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_flexipage.htm) in the APIs), which cannot be directly addressed. They can be added as standalone tabs (in Salesforce1 or Lightning Desktop) or to override record pages in Lightning Desktop. So I'm afraid the answer is no, pages that are created in App Builder can't be in a visualforce page.

You can put your Lightning Components [directly on Lightning Pages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder.htm).

You can also put a Visualforce page in a Lightning Page by using the Visualforce component in App Builder.